# Dagger 1.1.0 +maven+eclipse : Please ensure that code generation was run for this module

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, dependency-injection, dagger

I am trying to run dagger 1.1.0 but I am still getting the exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Module adapter for class com.test.MyAppModule could not be loaded. Please ensure that code generation was run for this module.
```

In my pom.xml I have:

```
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.squareup.dagger</groupId>
          <artifactId>dagger</artifactId>
          <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.squareup.dagger</groupId>
          <artifactId>dagger-compiler</artifactId>
          <version>1.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.squareup</groupId>
          <artifactId>javawriter</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

I also tried with optional = true. It compiles fine with dagger version 1.0.1, but i just can't make it work with 1.1.0. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Is this happening on the command line or within Eclipse only?

Comment: Eclipse only, haven't tried command line yet

Comment: Can you verify if this is happening on the command line as well?

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I experience the same problem.

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem.Did you resolve this? If so can you post your findings ?